# Trim number of digits in microseconds in PHP

Tags: php, date

Please how can i show only 3 digits microseconds, the code below shows 5 and i want only 3 digits

`$date = new \DateTime(); $dateTime = $date->format('YmdHisv');`

Comment: Can you give an example? What do you get, and what do you want? Note that there's a difference between microseconds and milliseconds.

Comment: You're not getting "5 digits microseconds", you're getting "2 digits of seconds + 3 digits of milliseconds". Try looking at it with a format that's not completely smushed together, like `'Y-m-d H:i:s.v'`.

Answer (score 0):

simply use substr for trimming in PHP

```
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $dateTime = $date->format('YmdHisv');
    echo substr($dateTime, 0, 3);
```

Comment: Don't you mean `echo substr($dateTime, 0, -2);`? See; [PHP fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1608c4a0ee6123171c98301c93afd13d63f99d1)

Comment: he said "how can I show only 3 digits microseconds" I don't know what he tries to do.

Comment: Yes, the question is a bit confusing. That's why I asked for an example.

Comment: if he explains a little bit with an example. I'll improve my answer according to that.